# Filter lines based on certain string and then print only some attributes greater

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I have a big text file with million of log lines.

I would like to filter all the lines which satisfy following criteria

1. url should be `url=/v2/testB`
2. totalTime value should be greater than 500

```
INFO|id=1|totaltime=5000|httpmethod=POST|url=/v1/testA
INFO|id=2|totaltime=200|httpmethod=POST|url=/v2/testB
INFO|id=3|totaltime=1000|httpmethod=POST|url=/v2/testB
INFO|id=4|totaltime=501|httpmethod=POST|url=/v2/testB
```

result:-

```
id=3,totaltime=1000
id=4,totaltime=501
```

I have tried using multiple awk and then putting if block, I wonder, it can be done quickly? Thanks !

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
value=`echo $line|grep "url=/v2/testB" | awk -F"totaltime=" '{ print $2}'| awk -F"|" '{ print $1}'`
if (( $value > 500 )); then
    echo $line
fi
done < file.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this awk:

```sh
awk -F '|' -v OFS=, '$NF == "url=/v2/testB" {v=$3; sub(/^totaltime=/, "", v); if (v+0 > 500) print $2, $3}' file

id=3,totaltime=1000
id=4,totaltime=501
```

To make it more readable:

```sh
awk -F '|' -v OFS=, '
$NF == "url=/v2/testB" {
   v = $3
   sub(/^totaltime=/, "", v)
   if (v+0 > 500)
      print $2, $3
}' file
```

If you have `gnu-awk` then it can be reduced to:

```sh
awk -F '|' -v OFS=, '$NF == "url=/v2/testB" &&
gensub(/^totaltime=/, "", "1", $3)+0 > 500 {print $2, $3}' file
```

`v+0` is shorthand in awk to covert a string value to number.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F'|' -v OFS=',' '{split($3,t,/=/)} $5=="url=/v2/testB" && t[2]>500{print $2, $3}' file
id=3,totaltime=1000
id=4,totaltime=501
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be in luck:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=","}
           { url = substr($NF,index($NF,"=")+1)
             totaltime = substr($3,index($3,"=")+1)
           }
           (url == "/v1/testB") && (totaltime+0 > 500) { print $2,$3 }
          ' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk -F'\\||totaltime=' '$NF=="url=/v2/testB" && $4>500{print $2",totaltime="$4}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Following is the detailed explanation for above code.

- Setting field separator by using `-F` option in `awk` program.
- Setting field separators to `|` and `totaltime=` for all the lines of Input_file.
- In main program, checking conditions:
  a- If `$NF`(last field) is equal to `url=/v2/testB` AND
  b- 4th field is greater than 500 then do:
- print 2nd field of current line followed by string `,totaltime=` followed by 4th field as per required output by OP.

Answer (score 0):

All the awk solutions are great, and if that is a solution use them.

If you wanted to fix your Bash effort, you can do:

```
while IFS='|' read -r id ti; do
    [[ "${ti#*=}" -gt 500 ]] && printf "%s,%s\n" "$id" "$ti"
done < <(grep 'url=/v2/testB$' file | cut -d '|' -f 2,3)
```

Alternatively, you can eliminate `cut` and keep all five fields:

```
while IFS='|' read -r c1 c2 c3 c4 c5; do
    [[ "${c3#*=}" -gt 500 ]] && printf "%s,%s\n" "$c2" "$c5"
done < <(grep 'url=/v2/testB$' file)
```

Either prints:

```
id=3,totaltime=1000
id=4,totaltime=501
```